# How to initiate a timer every time an incoming call is received?

Tags: java, android, service

I want a timer to start when an incoming call is received and stop when the call is picked up or is ended by the the caller.

To put it simply, I want the ring time. Yes, the time the phone is ringing. I know that I would need a service, but how do I let those conditions as a trigger for the timer to start?

I tried searching the API for an ring time duration constant but to no avail. I am a beginner, so a lot of detail would be appreciated and preferred.

Answer (score 2):

You must use `BroadcastReceivers`. To get the phone state you need permission `READ_PHONE_STATE`. Then you can start a timer when it is ringing and stop when the call is picked you.

Comment: No Service is different from `BroadcastReceivers`. Read the doc http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html for more info. Tutorials: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html